# php converting string into datetime format

Tags: php, date, datetime, format

I am having problems converting a string into datetime format in order to store variable into a datetime-type field of a sql table

value of $timestamp:
    2019-02-23T08:30:03.77

```
$datum2 = substr($timestamp,0,19);
$datum2 = str_replace('T',' ', $datum2);
echo $datum2 ."<br>";

--> 2019-02-23 08:30:03  .... echo output looks ok to me

$datum2 = date_format($datum2,'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

--> error message

Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface

Thank you for any hints
Stefan

Answer (score 1):

Check below code:

```
$date = '2019-02-23 08:30:03'; 
$datum2 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date));
```

You can convert string date to timestamp and later can change to date format. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `date_create` function on `$timestamp`:

```
$datum2 = date_format(date_create($timestamp),'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```